# Problems with Windows Presentation Foundation WPF application with Entity Framework when reverting to .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, backwards-compatibility, .net-framework-version

Our company is working on a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) application that uses .NET Framework 4.5.

Our WPF application uses Entity Framework. Our Technical Lead wanted to revert back to .NET Framework 3.5.

We reverted the application to .NET Framework 3.5, and so our Entity Framework version also reverts back to 3.5.0.0 version.

However, problems like `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure` showing up as invalid

`DbContext` shows up as Invalid.

We need to revert back to .NET Framework 3.5. Could someone please tell us how we should resolve the problems with Entity Framework?

Comment: What is the reason for such a "backwards" decision? You're not going to make your life easier by going back to legacy code..... what is your "Tech Lead" trying to accomplish by going back to .NET 3.5 ?? Wouldn't it be much more productive to solve whatever issues you might face with .NET 4.5 instead??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext` was introduced in [Entity Framework 4.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx). Before that version you have to use the [DatabaseContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

It is not trivial to do such a big change back to .NET 3.5. I think you will have many problems specially the absence of methods that are present in EF4.5. Furthermore you cannot use any `async` method.

Why do you want to target .NET3.5? Is it because of the lacking support of Windows XP in .NET 4.5? If so, consider using .NET4.0. Then you can use a higher version EF that supports DbContext.